# Android : Universal image downloader cache path

Tags: universal-image-loader

Am using UIL to download images and i want tht images to be saved in cache only. So in configuration i have enabled cacheInMemory() options. But when i check my app info in settings its still shows 0.00B. Where exactly my images are getting stored if i enable cacheInMemory() options. ?

```
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.item_fine_dining).cacheInMemory().build();
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            getApplicationContext()).threadPoolSize(3)
            .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
            .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1)
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory().enableLogging()
            .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
            .enableLogging().build();
```

Comment: If you enabled `cacheInMemory()` option so images are stored in memory.

Comment: There is `cacheOnDics()` options for caching on the files system (or SD card).

Comment: but when i check cache size it still shows 0.0B. How is this possible ? and how can i get path of particular image . [ saved path ].I want to check whether image already saved or not . any function available for this ?? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: am not saving in sdcard. so am using displayoptions like this  options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .showStubImage(R.drawable.item_fine_dining).cacheInMemory().build();

Comment: when images are downloaded it will be loaded to listview. Based on user selected row in listview , I need to send e mail to user. for mail i have to attach image. So i need path of the image. How can i get saved location path when cacheInMemory option is enabled ? Please hep me

Comment: Enable `cacheOnDisc()` option.

Comment: Thanks for the infor. but I dont want to save in disc. I want to save in memory. If i select "cacheInMemory()" this option, where exactly images are getting stored ? is it inside /data/data/com.chowzter/cache ? [application cache which is not available to other app and user cannot view this ] .

Comment: "Memory" is a RAM memory, "Disc" is file system of device (SD card too). "/data/data/..." is a file system. Enable ".cacheOnDisc()" and use `DiscCacheUtil` to get cached images by URL.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.But is there any option to save in internal memory instead of RAM. i mean to say appliction's internal memory. [getApplicationContext().getCacheDir() ] So that user can clear cache .

Comment: Set `.discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir()))` in configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me :) Am already doing that now.. aweseome library :) :)